# how to set the default screen in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have created a ionic app with many screens. When I close the ionic app and then open it, it navigates to the Login screen. I want the ionic app to show a default screen. How do I do that. My code for logout functionality is as follows:

```js
async prosesLogout(){
    this.storage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
       message: 'Log Out Successful',
       position:"middle",
       color:"primary",
       duration: 3000
    });
    toast.present();
}
```

What should be added to this code. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: when I close the ionic app without logging out and then open it again, It shows me the login screen. I want it to show some other screen. What should be done for that

Answer (score 1):

You can check login data from storage in  `app.component.ts` file and if login data found you can navigate to next page

app.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(){
        this.initializeApp();
    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {

            let loginData = this.storage.getLoginData() // you can get login data from you storage
            if(loginData){
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }
            else{
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this says getLoginData is not there in storage

Comment: First you need to store user profile info when first login, and add check when app open for if user info is present or not. `getLoginData()` is custom function you have to create your own custom function to get login data. For storage you can use browser localstorage or Ionic storage.

Comment: Ref : Ionic - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage, Browser - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp